# Actionscript 3.0 MovieClip frame change listener

Tags: actionscript-3, listener, frame, movieclip

I have a scene with a monster. Monster blinks its eyes. Eyes blinking is a separate MovieClip.
Under some conditions, monster opens its mouth. Mouth opening is a separate MovieClip as well. At this moment I have to hide eyes MovieClip. As soon as monster closes its mouth, I must make eyes blinking visible again.

My idea is to have some listener that listens to Mouth_opening MovieClip. When Mouth opening's currentFrame changes from 1 to 2, I will hide eyes. When it changes from 2 to 1, I will show it back.

So, the question is: how do I listen to currentFrame changes?
Event.ENTER_FRAME is not appropriate: it's being called every render frame, not only when currentFrame changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "frameChange" event in ActionScript so you need to come up with your own system. For example, you can make it work by listening to `enterFrame` then monitor the current frame - when it changes call your function. Something like that should work:

```
private var lastFrame:int = -1;

// Then add this in your constructor:
addEventListener("enterFrame", onEnterFrame);

private function onEnterFrame(event:*):void {
    if (lastFrame != currentFrame) {
        onFrameChanged();
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
    }
}


private function onFrameChanged():void {
    trace("The frame has changed to " + currentFrame);
}
```